# C++ Signature Scanner output wrong

Tags: c++, hex

I'm making a Signature Scanner in c++, and to test it out I am injecting into steam and comparing the first 10 bytes.

```
#define sig "\x4D\x5A\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00"
```

When I arrived to the 3rd byte x90, the output I am getting was:

```
steam: \x4D\x5A\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00
sig: \x4D\x5A\xFFFFFF90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00
```

Here is my entire source:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#define sig "\x4D\x5A\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00"

#pragma comment( lib, "Psapi" )

HANDLE thread = NULL;

DWORD getImageSize( MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION &memInfo )
{
if( !VirtualQuery( GetModuleHandleA(NULL), &memInfo, sizeof( memInfo ) ) )
    return 0x00;

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dosHeader     = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)memInfo.AllocationBase;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *peHeader      = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((unsigned long)dosHeader + (unsigned long)dosHeader->e_lfanew);

if( peHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE )
    return 0x00;

return peHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
}

DWORD scan( HANDLE hProc, const DWORD length = 0x200, DWORD base = 0x00 )
{   
  if(!base )
    return base;

if( AllocConsole() )
    AttachConsole( GetCurrentProcessId() );

freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );

SetConsoleTitleW( L"Test Console" );

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo;
int sigLength = sizeof( sig );

const DWORD size = getImageSize( memInfo );
unsigned char *pBase;
pBase = (unsigned char *)base;

printf( "Size = %d\n", size );

if( !size )
    return size;

for( int i(0); i < size; i++ )
{
    printf( "\\x%02X", pBase[i] );
    printf( "\\x%02X", (unsigned char *)sig[i] );

    if( i && (i % 10 == 0))
        system( "PAUSE" );

    if( pBase[i] == sig[i] )
    {
        for( int j(i), k(0); k < sigLength; j++, k++ )
        {
            if( sig[k] == '?' )
                continue;

            if( pBase[j] != sig[k] )
                break;

            if( j == (sigLength-1) )
                return (DWORD)&pBase[i];
        }
    }
}

printf( "\n" );

system( "PAUSE" );

return 0x00;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain ( HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
if( dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
{
    DWORD base = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA( NULL );
    scan( GetCurrentProcess(), 0x200, base );
}

return TRUE;
}
```

The only thing I could think of is that the value is being seen as signed, but doesn't %02X make it unsigned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier, `%02X`, says to print the value using uppercase hex letters.  Nothing about signed or unsigned.

If you want unsigned, you can use the argument `h` or `hh`, as in the [printf format specifiers.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

I personally would cast the argument to unsigned in the call to {f}printf.

Comment: Actually, `%X`, `%x`, `%o` and `%u` all assume that the value passed is an unsigned integer type.  However, `char` values undergo 'usual conversions' when passed to `printf()` and end up as an `int`, and if the `char` type is signed, values from 0x80..0xFF can end up as negative integers. However, your advice to cast the character to `unsigned char` (assuming that's what you meant) is correct.  The `hh` modifier was added to C99; it may not be available on Windows.  I'd need to check C89 for the `h` modifier on `printf()`, but I'd not be surprised to find it too was added in C99. MSVC is C89.

Comment: I was meaning prefixing with '0' as in '%02X', not that X meant unsigned. Oh my, how did I miss that? I had already tried type-casting, but I was casting to (unsigned char *) instead of (unsigned char) haha thanks for your help guys - it worked a treat :)